# i am trying to print a table in infinite loop in kotlin but getting this (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space)

Tags: java, loops, kotlin

> need help to resolve this error
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

```
 Fun main(){
    Val num = 2
    Var i = 1
    while(i >= 1)
    {
    Println(num * i)
    }
    }
```

Comment: You Println statement is probably creating a new object to hold the value of num * i for ever iteration of your while loop. Because your while loop doesn't have a condition to escape. The scope the loop is in and all the objects in it, are kept in memory. That loop probably is getting iterated through 1000s of times a second. So you're creating 1000's of objects and they have to be kept somewhere... Till there isn't any more space.
In a practical program you would never have a loop without some sort of escape condition. So it's not really an issue.

Comment: Can you copy-paste your actual code? This isn't compilable. I don't see anything above that would cause it to use increasingly more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Value of i is always 1 and you are going in infinite loop so that's why out of memory is coming try to change the condition and you will get the output hope this helps

```
Fun main(){
    Val num = 2
    Var i = 1
    while(i >= 1)
    {
    Println(num * i)
    i=i-1
    }
    }
```

Comment: An infinite loop won't cause memory to be used up if it doesn't repeatedly allocate new objects that are referenced in a higher scope. Almost every app with a UI is based on infinite loop(s)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `println` kicks off some internal operations that use memory, and if you spray a lot of them quickly enough, you can get an OOM (before garbage collection has a chance to run, I'm assuming)

[exhibit A](https://pl.kotl.in/b1Cvi1LAI)

```
fun main() {
    while (true) {
        println("uh oh")
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode (StringCoding.java:149) 
 at java.lang.StringCoding.decode (StringCoding.java:193) 
 at java.lang.StringCoding.decode (StringCoding.java:254)
```